# Проблема с отображением информации по файлах в директории

Tags: файлы, php

Здравствуйте.
Суть вопроса - есть директория, там текстовые файлы, я получаю список файлов и вывожу на экран

```
//Предпросмотр всех загруженных файлов
$current_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php-edu/upload/FILE_FOLDER/';
$dir = opendir($current_dir);
echo 'Каталог выгрузки: <b>'.basename($current_dir).'</b>'."<br />";
echo 'Содержимое каталога: <ul>';
while (false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        echo '<li><a href="filedetails.php?file='.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
closedir($dir);
```

Далее предполагается, что нажав на ссылку файла я получу его детальные характеристики (код исполняемого скрипта)

```
clearstatcache();
$current_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php-edu/upload/FILE_FOLDER/';
$file = basename($current_dir); //возвращает имя файла без каталога

echo '<h3>Данные о файле '.$file.'</h3>';
echo 'Последнее отображение: '.date('j F Y H:i', fileatime($file)).'<br />';
echo 'Последняя модификация: '.date('j F Y H:i', filemtime($file)).'<br />';

$user = posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file));
echo 'Владелец файла: '.$user['name'].'<br />';

$group = posix_getgid(fileowner($file));
echo 'Группа файла: '.$group['name'].'<br />';

echo 'Права доступа: '.decoct(fileperms($file)).'<br />';

echo 'Тип файла: '.filetype($file).'<br />';
echo 'Размер файла: '.filesize($file).' байтов <br />';
```

Проблема в том, что бы я не делал, я всегда получаю описание папки-родителя (FILE_FOLDER), а не выбранного мной файла.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так написал.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Так $file = basename($current_dir); а что такое $current_dir? Путь к директории. О файле речь не идет.

Comment: я пытался подставлять имя файла - не работает. подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае, правильно сделать? этот листинг написал из книжки, странно, что не работает.

Comment: выкиньте книжку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас написано

```
$current_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php-edu/upload/FILE_FOLDER/';
$file = basename($current_dir); //возвращает имя файла без каталога
```

basename выдает последний элемент пути, естественно он всегда  FILE_FOLDER,

где-то вам надо приделать **`$_GET['file']`**, не забывайте о предосторожностях (basename как раз хорошо подрезает всякие relative path)

Comment: @eicto Сделал как и сказали. GET'ом получил текущее имя файла, теперь информацию показывает относительно файла, но проблема в том, что, собственно, информацию не показывает - пустые поля, дата сброшена на самое начало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что еще может быть не так?

Comment: так наверное надо путь подставить. что нить типа 

    $file=$current_dir."".basename($_GET['file']);